# Godot Engine using groups

Tags: godot, gdscript

I just downloaded Godot Engine, and I tried to use a group to activate 3 buttons with a 4th one.

that was the line that should do this:

```
get_tree().call_group("Buttons", "pressed")
```

But nothing happnes.
I did everything that was written in the tutorial, but as it seems, that line do not want to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
get_tree().call_group("Buttons", "pressed")
```

Calls the method `pressed` on the objects in the group `"Buttons"`. If it does nothing, it means that there are no objects in the group `"Buttons"` which have a `pressed` that does something.

To reiterate the failure points are:

- There are no objects in the `"Buttons"` group.
- There are objects in the `"Buttons"` group, and none of them have a method `pressed`.

Or, if you prefer to look at it this from the `pressed` method:

- There is no method `pressed`.
- There is a method `pressed`, but none of the objects in the `"Buttons"` group have it.

Addendum: Well, there is another failure point: `get_tree()`. It could return `null` (the code is running in a `Node` which is not currently in the scene tree). Or it might not be defined (the code is running in something that is not a `Node`). But you would have an error. And you would see an error, right? RIGHT?

---

Now, what are you trying to do? What does it mean to "activate a button"? This is guesswork: You want to emit a `"pressed"` signal from the buttons.

To emit a signal, you use `emit_signal` like this:

```
object.emit_signal("name_of_the_signal", ...)
```

Notice, the method is `emit_signal`. **Signals are not methods**. We can use `call_group` to call the `emit_signal` method:

```
get_tree().call_group("Buttons", "emit_signal", "pressed")
```

Comment: get_tree().call_group("Buttons", "emit_signal", "pressed")